# How to realise padding along the specific axis in TensorFlow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I would have a tensor A with the shape of (16, 256, 256, 3) (16 is the batch size, 256 is the size of image block, 3 is the number of channels of image block). I would like to use the "PadLayer" in TensorFlow to pad zeros along the second and third dimension of the tensor A (that is 256).

For example, the padding result should be (16, 300, 300, 3). I would like to ask how to realise this? How to set up the 'paddings' parameter in TensorFlow.

Many thanks for help!

Comment: What are you referring to with _the "PadLayer"_? Do you mean the [`tf.pad`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad) function? Or something like [this `PadLayer` from TensorLayer](https://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/layers.html#pad-layer-expert-api)? Or something else?

Comment: Hi Jdehesa, The "PadLayer" is the same as "tf.pad" function in tensorflow. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, if for example you want to pad with 22 elements at each side of the second and third dimensions (so `A` is centered within the padding), you could do `tf.pad(A, [(0, 0), (22, 22), (22, 22), (0, 0)])`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Hi Jdehesa, Many thanks for your kind help! It's solved! Thanks.